# Backbone and Rails redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm new with backbone and Rails. When I return to the index view in the last line, the index view is not updated with the new value created.

```
class App.Views.ProfilesIndex extends Backbone.View
template: JST['profiles/index']

initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(profiles: @collection))
    this
```

And this is my code for the new view

```
class App.Views.ProfilesNew extends Backbone.View
template: JST['profiles/new']

initialize: ->
    @collection = new App.Collections.Profiles()

events: ->
    'submit #new_profile': 'createProfile'

render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    this

createProfile: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    attributes = name: $('#new_profile_name').val()
    @collection.create attributes,
        success: -> Backbone.history.navigate("/profiles", {trigger: true})
```

So, I need to update the collection when the new element is created and returned to index view.

## Router

```
class App.Routers.Profiles extends Backbone.Router
routes:
    'profiles': 'index'
    'profiles/new': 'new'

initialize: ->
    @collection = new App.Collections.Profiles()
    @collection.fetch()

index: ->
    view = new App.Views.ProfilesIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
    
new: ->
    view = new App.Views.ProfilesNew()
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

Comment: When I return to the index view in the last line, the index view is not updated with the new value created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct `App.Collections.Profiles` collections. Your router has one:

```
class App.Routers.Profiles extends Backbone.Router
    #...
    initialize: ->
        @collection = new App.Collections.Profiles()
```

And your `ProfilesNew` view has its own:

```
class App.Views.ProfilesNew extends Backbone.View
    #...
    initialize: ->
        @collection = new App.Collections.Profiles()
```

Your `createProfile` method adds the new profile to the `@collection` in the `ProfilesNew` view and then the router hands its `@collection` to the `ProfilesIndex` view:

```
index: ->
    view = new App.Views.ProfilesIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

I think you should have just one collection: the one in the router. Then hand that to the `ProfilesNew` view:

```
new: ->
    view = new App.Views.ProfilesNew(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

and remove the `initialize` method from `ProfilesNew`. A view's [`initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) will copy the `collection` option to `@collection` for you:

> There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, **`collection`**, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

Emphasis mine.